# Create view based on Big Query partitioned table where table name changes every day with the appended date like Table1_20210713

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

How can I create a view which should be applicable to all the dates. Right now if I remove the date from table1_20210713, it is throwing incorrect table error.

Select column1, column2 from `table1_20210713`
Union All
Select column1, column2 from `table2_20210713`

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve this using a wildcard table: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-wildcard-tables

For yours you would do something along the lines of

```
select column_1
  , column_2
from `project.dataset.table1_*`
```